# Where I can put link to popup with input for promo code?

Tags: popup, code

I am mocking up a very minimalistic user-account page, and I have a mockup:
[image]

This is mockup probably most important subpage. This page will be like "command center" for a user because he will do everything from this place. At this page will be statistics, option buy more queries, change password, etc. One of the options will be use promo code to add more queries to our account. And I have no idea where I can put link to popup with input for promo code.

Mockup subpage with promo code popup:

[image]

Where I click in a username (piotrex41), I can see popup with change password form, like popup with promo code.

Maybe you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: this is very vague, I don't know what your website is about and what promocode actually means and when will the user have to enter it.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Is the reason you want to put 'redeem' on this page that all user commands can only be done through this page? Are the other tabs just for displaying information then? Because right now there's a 'buy queries' tab on the side which kind of breaks that idea...

If the promo code adds more queries to the account, why not consolidate 'buy queries' and 'redeem promo' into a general 'increase queries' (with a better name, of course) page? They both help the user achieve the same end goal. Alternatively, if that seems like a waste of an entire page/you want to keep all actions on this 'control center' view, move the 'buy queries' functionality onto this page and group it together with 'redeem promo'.